# Including Bootstrap in an electron app built with electron-builder

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, electron, electron-builder

How do I include Bootstrap in an Electron app built with electron-builder? Ideally, I'd like to use the npm package so I my app/packages.json looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  }
}
```

but app/node_modules remains empty. I have the same dependency and devDependecy in my top-level packages.json but that makes not difference either in what ends up being packaged.

Do I have to copy them manually? Do I have to include it in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Packed into [asar](https://github.com/electron/asar) archive by default. If you mean not packaged app, but your project dir — npm install is not called, it is your responsibility to install dependencies to project dir.